# 0 objc_msgsend.. when i click Ok Button on alertview .. clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

[image: I attached the logs]When i pressed ok button that time application is crash due to 0 objc_msgsend ?

```
-(void)onBusinessSuccess:(id)dataObj
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Order" message:@"Order Successfully Discontinued." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alertView.tag = 1;
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"I am cliked");
    }
}
```

Comment: you set the delegates?

Comment: Yes The delegates are set into the .h file like @interface OrderRegionDiscontinueViewController : UITableViewController < UIPopoverControllerDelegate,BusinessObjectDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: Hi @llario i did like your code but not get success still it crash and same 0 msgsend :(

Comment: can you show the entire crash log please? oh, my answer is wrong sorry.. i tested your code and for me works

Comment: I attached the log image

Comment: Please confirm that the delegate of the UIAlertview is not being released after presenting, so when the alert is dismissed, it is not sending a message to it's delegate, which may be nil.  An other option is that the UIViewController that presents the alert view is released after it is presented. Please check if the alert delegate is not released after it is presented.

Comment: method 'onBusinessSuccess' work in a background thread?

Comment: Hey Hi Seya and llario Thanx i got the solution ....the problem was "UIViewController that presents the alert view is released after it is presented" thats why the it sending 0 msg

Comment: Thanx Seya your comment help me to find the solution thank you once again the UIViewController is release before the alertview show thats issue so fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments (added to an answer to others benefit):

When you crash on a "objc_msgSend()" you are most likely sending a messageto an already-freed object. Or you have a pointer, which is correct, but something have changed the objects contents.  Another cause can be the use of a dangling pointer that once pointed to the memory now occupied by your object. Occasionally objc_msgSend crashes because a memory error changed the runtime's own data structures, which then would cause trouble in the receiver object itself.

In this situation you need to check wheter or not, the delegate of the UIAlertview has been released after presenting, so when the alert is dismissed, it is not sending a message to it's delegate, which may be nil. An other option is that the UIViewController that presents the alert view is released after it is presented. Please check if the alert delegate is not released after it is presented.